# Setting up multiple HDMI Monitors on Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, multiple-monitors, hdmi, external-display

So I currently have like 3+ monitors in my house that are all using HDMI connections. On my computer I have USB 3/ USB 2 and and HDMI connection. Is there any type of device i can use that can extend my display to 2 or more of these monitors on my computer running Ubuntu?

I know there is an HDMI splitter but that only duplicates my current screen. Other than that it doesnt seem like these special docking stations work with Linux.

Answer (score 0):

If the USB 3 port is of type USB-C, then you may connect to it a
[USB C docking station with 2 HDMI ports](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=USB+C+docking+station+with+2+hdmi+ports&crid=1E2GZIW3A4WLO&sprefix=usb+c+docking+station+with+2+hdmi+ports%2Caps%2C228&ref=nb_sb_noss).

For this to work, your display adapter must be rated for 3 monitors.
Even if it is, you should still pay attention to the resolutions that it
supports for such a configuration.